# C++ Unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, constructor

I tried to create class object into another class with constructor, I got error that 'unresolved external symbol'.I research example codes and I could not find anything wrong in my code.`

LinkedList.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


template  <class T> class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(int Size);   
    list <T> data;
    int size;
    LinkedList* next;

};
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <class T> 
LinkedList <T> ::LinkedList() {

    size = 0;
    next = NULL;
}

template <class T>
LinkedList <T> ::LinkedList(int Size) {

    size = Size;
    next = NULL;
}
```

Cotp_connection.h

```
#pragma once
#include "connect_tcp.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"

class Cotp_connection {
public:
    Cotp_connection();
    Cotp_connection(int size);  
};
```

Cotp_connection.cpp

```
#include "Cotp_connection.h"

Cotp_connection::Cotp_connection() {
    LinkedList <uint8_t> list;
}

Cotp_connection::Cotp_connection(int size) {

    LinkedList <uint8_t> list(size);
}
```

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall LinkedList::LinkedList(void)" (??0?$LinkedList@E@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Cotp_connection::Cotp_connection(void)" (??0Cotp_connection@@QAE@XZ)  kkkkk_v2

Edit:If i editted my code this way it works.Okey but why it is works now,but not before ?

Cotp_connection.cpp

```
Cotp_connection::Cotp_connection() {
    LinkedList <uint8_t> list();
}

Cotp_connection::Cotp_connection(int size) {

    LinkedList <uint8_t> list((size));
}
```

Linkedlist.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


template  <class T> class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(int Size) :size(Size),next(NULL) {}; 
    list <T> data;
    int size;
    LinkedList* next;

};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of code snippets. You most likely have a buffer overflow somewhere... Show at least ths stack trace.

Comment: Why are you using `vector<string> *objects;` instead of `vector<string> objects;`? You are using `new`, as well as `malloc`/`calloc`. You need to `delete` what you `new`ed, but you need to `free` what you `malloc`ed. Are you sure you are not mixing them up somewhere? Why don't you use `std::vector` for your buffers as well?

Comment: You would have a much better chance of seeing what the error is if you used `std::vector<char>`, `std::vector<uint8_t>`, etc. and not raw pointers.  The code looks like `C` code with a couple of C++ syntax thrown in.  You even have `string jk` declared locally, but refuse to use `std::string` anywhere else except for the `vector<string>`, and even that need not be a pointer.

Comment: I want to make it faster because of this i use pointer. I sure about that make them free and delete.When error occured in debug mode, i press continue ,code continue to work. Sometimes error occured at this line ,sometimes code is running perfectly.

Comment: @SerhanErkovan Using `std::vector` for this (properly) is not slower than using manual dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @uneven_mark okay i will try this

Comment: @SerhanErkovan for the future, deleting your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379777/exception-thrown-at-xmemory-file?noredirect=1#comment103127327_58379777) (for those who can see it) and reposting it almost verbatim because nobody would reopen it is not the best way to go about this.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Okay sorry about this but my question is hanging up 'hold on' situation even thought i edited my code. I need an answer. Sorry for this it would not happened again.

Comment: @SerhanErkovan anyway in both cases you were asked for a minimal reproducible example, that is something self-contained which we can try on our machines. As Jabberwocky said you only produced snippets of code which does not help us replicate your problem. A nice side-effect of producing that self-contained example is that you may notice what the problem is by yourself!